# how to use react function in codepen?

Tags: reactjs, codepen

#### How to use React functions in CodePen?

I wrote a react function in CodePem to test React hooks, however it constantly keeps reporting errors: `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined.`

**My Code:**

```
import {useState, useEffect,useRef } from 'react';

function Test() {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
  const prevRef = useRef();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    // const ref = useRef();
    console.log('ref----', prevRef.current);
    prevRef.current = count;
  })
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div onClick={() => setCount(count+1)}>+1</div>
      <div>{`count: ${count}`}</div>
      <div>{`precount: ${prevRef.current}`}</div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Test />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: I think you'll have to import ReactJS through CDN. CodeSandbox is more preferred to write ReactJS code.

Comment: Please Google for "react codepen," there are unlimited examples. Make special note of the settings of the Javascript pane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a package by adjusting the settings in your Pen.

Take a look at the following image for reference:

[image]

By doing so, it will automatically generate the necessary import statement:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from 'https://esm.sh/react@18.2.0';
import ReactDOM from 'https://esm.sh/react-dom@18.2.0';
```

To help you understand this process, I've created a sample code on CodePen. You can refer to this example to implement it yourself.

Here is the codepen link to the sample code: https://codepen.io/camel2243/pen/ExdBRar